# Find the minimum number of steps to decrease N to zero

Tags: c, recursion, minimum

I'm facing some difficulties in the last few days while trying to finish the following task, I hope you guys can assist :

I'm given a single number N, and I'm allowed to perform any of the two operations on N in each move :

**One** - If we take 2 integers where N = x * y , then we can change the value of N to the maximum between x and y.

**Two** - Decrease the value of N by 1.

I want to find the minimum number of steps to reduce N to zero.
This is what I have so far, I'm not sure what is the best way to implement the function to find the divisor (someFindDevisorFunction), and if this '**f**' function would actually produce the required output.

```
  int f(int n)
{
  int div,firstWay,secondWay;
  if(n == 0)
    return 0;

  div = SomefindDivisorFunction(n);
  firstWay = 1 + f(n-1);
  if(div != 1)
  {
    secondWay = 1 + f(div);
    if (firstWay < secondWay)
        return firstWay;
    return secondWay;
  }

  return firstWay;
}
```

For example, if I enter the number 150 , the output would be : 
75 - 25 - 5 - 4 - 2 - 1 - 0

Comment: I don't understand: for 150 I would say:
150=15*10 => 15. 15=5*3=> 5, ..., which is one step less than your proposed solution.

Comment: I'm not grasping why your output has 75 as the first step for 150.  Why not 15, since 150 = 15 * 10 and 15 = max(15, 10)?  It looks to me like you'll get the most rapid convergence to zero by picking a and b to be the integer cofactors that are closest to sqrt(N).

Comment: What is your question? A different approach than the simple brute force you have shown? The code for `SomefindDivisorFunction()`? Please be more specific. If it is the code for the function, then consider focusing your question on that part,

Comment: Did you forget a piece of the question? for example, something about whether a and b are relatively prime? otherwise, as suggested here, you should factor it so that the two factors are as close as possible to sqrt(N).

Comment: Please state your question explicitly.

Comment: What is a step? Is finding `a` and `b` also considered a step or multiple steps?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I'll state my question, how would you implement the function to find the divisor, in a way that you wouldn't miss the best way with minimum number of steps for zeroing N?

Comment: Robert, finding a and b is not considerd as a step

Comment: You usually use dynamic programming for this kind of problems, and start from basic problems. I.e. `steps[1]` would be the number of steps to reach zero from `1`. Then you construct `steps[2]`, then `steps[3]`, and so on. In each step, you already have all the answers for the smaller problems solved. For example, with `150`, you would already know that `steps[15]` is smaller than `steps[75]`.

Comment: As the problem is stated in the question, for any positive N, we have N → −1 (since N = −1•−N and −1 = max(−1, −N)) → −2 (by decrement) → 2 (since −2 = −1•2) → 1 (by decrement) → 0 (by decrement).

Comment: @אברגיליעקובו Why did you remove the code from your post?

Comment: Wanted to update, but it didn't work as I expected. brought it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this a recursive or iterative problem.

OP's approach hints at recursive.

---

A recursive solution follows:

At each step, code counts the steps of the various alternatives:

```
steps(n) = min(
  steps(factor1_of_n) + 1,
  steps(factor2_of_n) + 1,
  steps(factor3_of_n) + 1,
  ...
  steps(n-1) + 1)
```

The coded solution below is inefficient, but it does explore all possibilities and gets to the answer.

```
int solve_helper(int n, bool print) {
  int best_quot = 0;
  int best_quot_score = INT_MAX;
  int quot;
  for (int p = 2; p <= (quot = n / p); p++) {
    int rem = n % p;
    if (rem == 0 && quot > 1) {
      int score = solve_helper(quot, false) + 1;
      if (score < best_quot_score) {
        best_quot_score = score;
        best_quot = quot;
      }
    }
  }

  int dec_score = n > 0 ? solve_helper(n - 1, false) + 1 : 0;

  if (best_quot_score < dec_score) {
    if (print) {
      printf("/ %d ", best_quot);
      solve_helper(best_quot, true);
    }
    return best_quot_score;
  }
  if (print && n > 0) {
    printf("- %d ", n - 1);
    solve_helper(n - 1, true);
  }
  return dec_score;
}

int main() {
  int n = 75;
  printf("%d ", n);
  solve(n, true);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Output

```
75 / 25 / 5 - 4 / 2 - 1 - 0
```

---

Iterative

TBD

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll test it when I reach home. However, I want to try and find how to do it more efficient, in a recursive way.

Comment: Remember to make it function right, before efficiency.  It is easy to make faster, yet not arrive at the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you start looking for a divisor with 2, and work your way up, then the last pair of divisors you find will include the largest divisor.  Alternatively you can start searching with divisor = N/2 and work down, when the first divisor found will have be largest divisor of N.

Comment: True that working ones way or or down will find the largest divisor, yet it is unclear that when considering step 1, finding the largest divisor in each step will result in the fewest steps.   Perhaps using a not-the-largest- divisors at an early stage results in the fewest steps?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int minmoves(int n){
    if(n<=3){
        return n;
    }
    int[] dp=new int[n+1];
    Arrays.fill(dp,-1);
    dp[0]=0;
    dp[1]=1;
    dp[2]=2;
    dp[3]=3;
    int sqr;
    for(int i=4;i<=n;i++){
        sqr=(int)Math.sqrt(i);
        int best=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(sqr >1){
            if(i%sqr==0){
                int fact=i/sqr;
                best=Math.min(best,1+dp[fact]);
            }
            sqr--;
        }
        best=Math.min(best,1+dp[i-1]);
        dp[i]=best;
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

Comment: This seems like a Java code and the OP was tagging for C. And code-only answers are generally not helpful.