# Way to represent an object in C or dealing with multiple value return

Tags: c, object

I was wondering if you might be able to help, I'm trying to "convert" some code that was written in javascript to 'C' code, but I'm not sure how to deal with the object :

```
function updateObj(o, k) {
  return {
    n: o.n + 1,
    way: k + "-" + o.way
  }
}

function steps(k) {
  if (k == 1) {
    return {
      n: 2,
      way: "1-0<BR>"
    };
  }
  let case1 = updateObj(steps(k - 1),k);
  for (i = 2; k % i > 0; i++);
  if (k == i) {
    return case1;
  }
  let case2 = updateObj(steps(k / i),k);
  if (case1.n < case2.n) return case1
  else return case2;
}

document.write(steps(291).way);
```

How would you transfer it to 'C' ?
Here is my try :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))


int steps(int num);

int main() {
    int res;
    res = steps(150);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int steps(k)
{

    int i = 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1;
    for (int i = 2; k%i > 0; i++);
    if (k == i) {
        return steps(k - 1);
    }
    return 1 + MIN(steps(k - 1), steps(k / i));
}
```

Comment: What about structs?

Comment: I would rather not to use structs, unless I don't have a choise.

Comment: You don't have the choice in C. There is not really "objects" nor "classes" like you can find in other languages, else if you do it yourself, which is a bit tricky

Comment: The algorithm itself looks inefficient no matter language. Consider dropping recursion for a vast performance boost. A compiler is unlikely to be able to unroll this recursion.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471588/find-the-minimum-number-of-steps-to-decrease-n-to-zero)?

Comment: Returning multiple objects from a function is not the hard part of this problem. Your JavaScript code is concatenating strings. The memory for that is automatically managed by JavaScript. In C, you will need to do it yourself. Or find a different way to print the answer without accumulating a string.

Comment: implementing `MIN` like that would be inefficient, since each parameter would be **evaluated twice**, and that'll give surprising results if the expression has a side effect. Write an inline function instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a close mapping of javascript to 'C' code.

```
// Include needed headers.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Form a struct
typedef struct {
  int n;
  char *way;  // Code will need to manage the strings - oh the joy of C!
} function;

function updateObj(function o, int k) {
  // Body left for OP to implement
  // Determine concatenation memory needs
  // Allocate
  // Concatenate
  // Free `o` resources
  // Form `function`
}

function steps(int k) {
  if (k == 1) {
    //     v---Compound Literal -----------------------v  Since C99
    return (function) {.n = 2, .way = strdup("1-0<BR>")};
  }
  function case1 = updateObj(steps(k - 1), k);
  int i;
  for (i = 2; k % i > 0; i++) {
    ;
  }
  if (k == i) {
    return case1;
  }
  function case2 = updateObj(steps(k / i), k);
  if (case1.n < case2.n) {
    function_free(case2);  // need to free resources in case2
    return case1;
  } else {
    function_free(case1);  // need to free resources in case1
    return case2;
  }
}

int main() {
  function f = steps(291);
  puts(f.way);
  function_free(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[structs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) might be what you are looking for.

They can be used to group some kind of data. In order to declare a structure that contains an integer and a char pointer, use:

```
struct S {
  int i;
  char *c;
};
```

Then you can do something like:

```
struct S function() {
  struct S s;
  s.i = 1;
  // more code
  return s;
}
```

If your structure is memory intensive you might want to put it on the heap and return a pointer.